# 32 bit shim and 64 bit shim in Windows Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, outlook-addin, shim

I have a VS2010 project which respectively creates a 32 bit Shim and a 64 bit Shim. It's an Outlook add-in that's been developed in .NET (hence the shimming).

With the advent of x64 not too long ago in Outlook (starting with 2010) we've been constantly making both x86 Windows Installer files and x64 Windows Installer files.

The real issue I am facing is when users download the MSI file(s) many of them do not know *what bitness their Outlook is*. So many times they install incorrect versions of the MSI and it doesn't load into their Outlook.

A standard COM error is reported in the Com Addins Dialog (Not loaded...a runtime error etc etc).

I want to avoid creating and deploying 2 separate MSI files...is there a possibility I can somehow have a single universal installer? Where users would just download the single MSI and the software would go and install/register into the respective `Program Files(x86)/Program Files`.

Is this possible?

I've looked into WiX and InstallShield but not very keen on working with those yet. Is it possible to do what I want to achieve using the built in Windows Installer in VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single MSI installer - it can be WiX, Windows Installer or anything else. You just need to add a custom action where you can detect the Outlook bitness and register the right loader on the machine. See [Windows Installer Setup With Custom Actions](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87ad51/3/) for more information.

Comment: what loader would you be talking about here? Can't I just launch a silent MSI installation if I found the correct bitness of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You still need two separate MSI files.  See:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367451(v=vs.85).aspx

especially where it says that 32-bit packages need to contain 32-bit components.

The issue is that your downloader/installer needs to detect the bitness of the Outlook on the system before downloading.

You could create 32-bit and 64-bit merge modules for your Outlook add-in, and include the 32-bit merge module in the 32-bit package, and both the 32-bit and 64-bit merge modules in your 64-bit setup, so that it registers both bitnesses. If the user migrated from a 32-bit Outlook to 64-bit they wouldn't need to re-install your product.

64-bit MSIs can't be installed on a 32-bit system, so the error being made must be installation of the 32-bit MSI on a 64-bit Outlook system. If the detection mechanism for 64-bit Outlook could be included in your 32-bit MSI as a launch condition you could prevent that error.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the "Merge Module"

Comment: In VS just create a merge module project, one of the installer project types, add your files and build the MSM. Then you can add it to your MSI setup projects.